# Adding SNS Topic Data protection policy from CDK (java)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, amazon-sns

Is this possible? I don't see anything for it in the Topic Builder, as any method on a created Topic or nothing obvious in the software.amazon.awscdk.services.sns...

Comment: Search for "dataProtection" on the [CfnTopic docs page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/java/software/amazon/awscdk/services/sns/CfnTopic.html).